# Directed graph (topological sort)

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, big-o, topological-sort

Say there exists a directed graph, `G(V, E)` (V represents vertices and E represents edges), where each edge (x, y) is associated with a weight (x, y) where the weight is an integer between 1 and 10.

Assume `s` and `t`are some vertices in `V`.

I would like to compute the shortest path from `s` to `t` in time O(m + n), where `m` is the number of vertices and `n` is the number of edges.

Would I be on the right track in implementing topological sort to accomplish this?  Or is there another technique that I am overlooking?

Comment: breadth-first search?

Comment: Why topological sort? Just because that has the same running time?

Comment: This has nothing to do with topological sort.

Comment: What about Dial's implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: Just use a bucket list as the priority queue. We can prove that there will be no more than 10 different labels in the queue at all times. Maybe that is Dial's implementation, maybe not, I don't know

Comment: I believe the bucket list approach is correct.  Dial's implementation does indeed make use of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you need to use for finding the minimal path from a given vertex to another in a weighted graph is [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Unfortunately its complexity is `O(n*log(n) + m)` which may be more than you try to accomplish.

However in your case the edges are special - their weights have only 10 valid values. Thus you can implement a special data structure(kind of a heap, but takes advantage of the small dataset for the wights) to have all operations constant.

One possible way to do that is to have 10 lists - one for each weight. Adding an edge in the data structure is simply append to a list. Finding the minimum element is iteration over the 10 lists to find the first one that is non-empty. This still is constant as no more than 10 iterations will be performed. Removing the minimum element is also pretty straight-forward - simple removal from a list.

Using Dijkstra's algorithm with some data structure of the same asymptotic complexity will be what you need.